# How to get recently viewed products by Customer Id in Model file Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, recently-viewed

- Create Recently Viewed Products for Model file in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Create an API with Mage2Gen

https://mage2gen.com/load/8cfec17a-a5ff-481e-9f36-2091e0237006

Now you can add the logic in

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Model/CustomerRecentlyViewedProductsManagement.php

Based on the following function in which a Recently Viewed Product Collection is returned when a Customer Id is available. Don't include the class in your construct because it is a block but copy it and add your own logic.

> getItemsCollection
>   in vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php

Then retrieve the current Customer Id through the

> Magento\Customer\Model\Session

Comment: Can you be more specific with Business Logic ?