# Magento 2 REST API: Create an API to fetch recently viewed products

Tags: magento2, rest-api, best-seller, recently-viewed

I need to create an API for fetching all the recently viewed products.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Recently viewed products by all customers or by specific customer?

Comment: You can try this module it provides lots of missing product APIs without any cost. https://marketplace.magento.com/webbytroops-add-on-product-apis.html and it has recently view API as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using: [WebbyTroops- Add-On Product APIs Module](https://marketplace.magento.com/webbytroops-add-on-product-apis.html)
Provides everything I needed.

Thank you everyone for replying!

Comment: I ordered, I got a email. But the download link was not available. There is no download link in the account section also. Fake?

Answer (score 0):

Here is description how to get recently viewed products by customer id:

[How to get recently viewed products by Customer Id in Model file Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251681/how-to-get-recently-viewed-products-by-customer-id-in-model-file-magento-2)